# Bitbucket server webhook to jenkins not posting after upgrade from stash

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket-server

We recently upgraded from Atlassian Stash 2.x to Atlassian Bitbucket Server 4.6.1. A lot of the post-commit hooks simply didn't work anymore because their plugins hadn't been updated, but one, the [Bitbucket Server Webhook for Jenkins](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.nerdwin15.stash-stash-webhook-jenkins/server/overview) isn't firing after a commit. The hook works when I hit the "Trigger Jenkins" button in its configuration window, but it's not firing after a new commit gets pushed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do some digging. First, I [turned on Bitbucket Server debug loggin via the UI](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/bitbucket-server-debug-logging-776640147.html#BitbucketServerdebuglogging-EnablingdebugloggingviatheUI). At that point, I saw some errors in the logs that pointed me to [an article about git hooks not firing](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/git-hook-scripts-are-not-executing-779171211.html?utm_campaign=in-app-help&utm_medium=in-app-help&utm_source=stash).

From there, I went digging in my bitbucket_home directory for the missing scripts and their file permissions. While I didn't find the 20_bitbucket_callback script, I did find a 20_stash_callback script in the same directory!

The article suggested checking their file permissions on the server, so I did.

`find . -name 20_stash_callback -printf "%p:  %u:%g %m\n"
find . -name pre-receive -printf "%p:  %u:%g %m\n"
find . -name post-receive -printf "%p:  %u:%g %m\n"`

Lo and behold, all the scripts had the permissions 644, or "Read/write for root, read-only for everyone else." I changed that with a little `find ... -exec`.

`sudo -u someuser find . -name 20_stash_callback -type f -exec chmod 774 {} \;
sudo -u someuser find . -name post-receive -type f -exec chmod 774 {} \;
sudo -u someuser find . -name pre-receive -type f -exec chmod 774 {} \;`

I still wasn't seeing my jenkins builds fire, when it occurred to me that I might need to rename the callback script to the one described in the documention.

```
sudo -u someuser find . -name 20_stash_callback -type f -exec rename 20_stash_callback 20_bitbucket_callback {} \;
```

After that, my the hook worked! And there was much rejoicing.

Note that the `someuser` account used above is the local user that our stash instance runs under. Make sure to change that for your needs if you use the above scripts.